# What does !this mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, this

As in this function, that toggles the 'completed' state of a todo item from true to false and back:

```
toggle: function() {
  this.save({
    completed: !this.get('completed') 
  });
}
```

Comment: `!(this.get('completed'))`

Comment: i.e. `!false === true` and `!true === false`, hence, toggling.

Comment: That's the 'logical not' operator. It's just taking `this.get('completed')` and inverting its value. So if it's true, it returns false, and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you know that `!` means negation (converts to boolean and returns the opposite value), what you posted is the same as

```
!(this.get('completed'))
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Notice that the `.` comes before the `!` on that table. That's why the `!` is associated with the whole expression, the `.` gets associated with `get()` before the `!` comes into play.

Comment: This combined with mVChr comment that '!false === true and !true === false, hence, toggling.' made it click, thanks!

Comment: @YPCrumble Was your question about what the `!` operator or about `!this`?

Comment: Was mainly your showing that the ! operator worked on the entire expression, not just 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is a technically fine general answer, and absolutely correct.

For your particular situation, you have a method in the current (`this`) object called `get()`, which returns a boolean value. So using the not operator (`!`) on the boolean return value from `get()` reverses it, so if `get()` returns `true`, the expression becomes `false` (etc). Meaning you are passing a value of the *opposite* of what's returned from `get()` as the value for the `completed` property of the object passed into the call to `save()`.

Comment: I have a feeling the question was more about what `!this` means, which is not what the code was doing. Not about what `!` does, I could be wrong

Comment: Ooops, from the OP's comment, it looks like they were confused about toggling

Comment: Sure, but if they are asking that particular question, I figured some clarification of what was going on also might help. Because "obviously" it's not '`!this`", as was pointed out by the earlier answer. I'm not suggesting the other answer is wrong, I was just adding more targeted info because I suspect they're a bit of a newbie. Cheers.